# Querying WordPress DB from normal sql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Disclaimer: I am not going to use any other ways I have a specific requirement.

All I want is to Join from posts table to the posts meta so that I can get the featured image per post. I am able to get the post via where clause post type is post and published but I don't know how to write join for MySql to get the featured image of each post

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
";

// Get an array of objects
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```

You may [check more here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but I do not have access to PHP in this case, so I need a plain MySql query.

Comment: Even for plain query you need to have access to php script if you are running it from a script.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is still looking for the sql needed here you go

```
        SET @term = "someterm"
        SELECT DISTINCT
            posts.id,
            posts.post_author,
            posts.post_title, 
            posts.post_date, 
            LEFT(posts.post_content,300) post_content,
            wpmeta.meta_value thumbnail
        FROM wp_posts posts 
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm ON posts.id = wpm.post_id 
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpmeta ON wpm.meta_value = wpmeta.post_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = posts.ID
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
        WHERE 
            post_status = 'publish' 
            AND posts.post_type = 'post' 
            AND wpm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
            AND wpmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
            AND 1 = 
                CASE
                    WHEN @term IS NULL THEN 1
                    WHEN @term IS NOT NULL AND t.term_id = @term THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
        ORDER BY post_date DESC
```